# Multi Agent System - Calculate a distance between agents using jade framework

Tags: java, eclipse, artificial-intelligence, agents-jade, multi-agent

I'm new user of Jade framework and I want to solve an exercise that asks to create 4 agents (3 taxi and 1 client) then calculate the distance between the client and the 3 taxi agents then I take the closest taxi to the client and communicate with him

The exercise is not clear enough so I didn't understand how can I calculate the distance between the client agent and the 3 taxi agents.

I would be grateful if someone explains to me how can I calculate the distance between agents or provide me a link to a tutorial that shows how to do it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, every your agent should have his current coordinates. use them to calculate distance (i.e client requires cordinates of every agent and handle their response)